# How to expose employer on individual dashboard without view/edit permissions?

Tags: user-dashboard, display

On Joomla 3.9.1 running CiviCRM 5.8.1. When users are logged-in to the website, we have a page that displays their member dashboard. Under the Your Contacts/Organizations, most people have nothing showing because they do not have a permissioned relationship with their organization. Only certain individuals should have a permissioned relationship that allows them to view and/or edit the organization information; however, I would like everyone to be able to see what organization they are connected to in this area. If I set it to view only, the individual can see the organization's profile, and I just want them to see the organization name and no other information, essentially to remove the hyperlink to the organization profile and remove the "Edit" and "Dashboard" links. What's the best way to accomplish this?
[image: Screenshot of member dashboard]

Comment: Can you have a look at the relationship between that contact and the employer. Has someone ticked that A has permission over B. Otherwise I would not expect A to be able to edit B

Comment: A can't edit B, just view it, but along with viewing it they can see all changes, contributions, updates, and other relationships. I want to avoid this by removing the ability to click and view the organization dashboard altogether.